# Cannot access System Settings. Unity-control-center crashed. Should I just wait for a fix upstream?

Tags: unity, pulseaudio, alsa, segmentation-fault, unity-control-center

I know this is a confirmed bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1544819

But it was almost a year ago, and I don't see any solutions. Was it supposed to be fixed in an update?

Right now I have no sound, or access to anything in the System Settings GUI.

I've tried everything to get at least the sound working, but nothing works.

Is there anything I can do?

Thank you.

Comment: the Bug Squad are always after more members. if a bug affects many users (lots of apport reports) it gets lots/more attention, but when it affects only a small number of users, the lack resources means many bug reports made thru launchpad get nowhere.   from my scan of bug-report a reboot would have fixed that reported issue. your description doesn't match (you didn't mention changing theme; and sound wasn't impacted by the bug).

Comment: The sound isn't working, to be clear. That really sucks. It seems to be affecting a whole many other things too.

Comment: i don't doubt it (sound not working sucks) - but the issue with sound is not related to the listed bug (which is a theme causing control-centre to segfault.  i'd suggest creating a new question relating to your sound issue on 'sound not working` with detail & not relate it to a segfault bug caused by a visual gtk-widget.  with regards your sound; I'd be checking your hardware is detected (eg. `lspci`, `lsmod`) first & go from there.